# How can I use a string out of and if-else statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

(First of all, I apologize if this is a basic question, but I'm new to coding)

What i want to do is to verify whether a string as a certain combination of characters and then replace them using an if-else statement, like this:

```
String RAWUserInput = sometextfield.getText().toString();
if (RAWUserInput.contains("example") {
   String UserInput = RAWUserInput.replace("example", "eg");
}else{
   String UserInput = RAWUserInput;}

sometextbox.setText(UserInput);
```

and then access the string outside of the if-else statement. I don't know how to do the last line because java can't find the string, What should I do?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you sure its `Cow`? :-} Declare your String variable outside `if-else`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the variable before the `if` statement.

```
String UserInput;
if (RAWUserInput.contains("example") {
   UserInput = RAWUserInput.replace("example", "eg");
}else{
   UserInput = RAWUserInput;
}
```

It will remain in scope after the `if` statement.  If the variable is declared inside the `if` block or `else` block (in between the braces), then it goes out of scope after the end of the block.

Also, the compiler is smart enough to determine that something is always assigned to `UserInput` in every case, so you won't get a compiler error that the variable may not have been assigned a value.

In Java, variables are typically named starting with a lowercase letter, unlike classes.  Normally, your variables would be named `userInput` and `rawUserInput`.

Answer (score 4):

When you declare a variable inside a block (`{ ... }`), the variable only exists inside that block.

You need to declare it outside the block, then *assign* it inside the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

```
String rawUserInput = sometextfield.getText().toString();
String userInput = ""; // empty
if (rawUserInput.contains("example") {
   userInput = rawUserInput.replace("example", "eg");
} else{
   userInput = rawUserInput;
}

sometextbox.setText(userInput);
```

Otherwise, save the else statement:

```
String rawUserInput = sometextfield.getText().toString();
String userInput = new String(rawUserInput); // copy rawUserInput, using just = would copy its reference (e.g. creating an alias rawUserInput for the same object in memory)
if (rawUserInput.contains("example") {
   userInput = rawUserInput.replace("example", "eg");
}
// no else here
```

Also, have a look at coding guidelines: indenting your code makes it more readable, starting temporary variable names with a lowercase is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

```
String UserInput = RAWUserInput.contains("example")? RAWUserInput.replace("example", "eg"): RAWUserInput;
```